Screen sharing via WhatsApp not possible?
I wanted to do a screen share via WhatsApp. However, the button that I could see on a Windows computer is missing. Is the function not yet available for macOS or am I missing something else?

It‘s not available on macOS.

Source: https://faq.whatsapp.com/1339237313658883
